# How to map array in destination with one item using Automapper

Tags: automapper

I have classes classes:

```
class A
{
    public string str1 { get; set; }
    public string str2 { get; set; }
    public string str3 { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string bstr1 { get; set; }
    public string bstr2 { get; set; }
}

class C
{
    public string cstr1 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<B> barr1 { get; set; }
}
```

How to create mapping like

```
this.CreateMap<A, C>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.cstr1, exp => exp.MapFrom(scc => scc.str1))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.barr1, exp => exp.MapFrom(scc => scc))
    .IgnoreAllNonExisting();

this.CreateMap<A, B[]>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest[0].bstr1, exp => exp.MapFrom(scc => scc.str2))
    .ForMember(dest => dest[0].bstr2, exp => exp.MapFrom(scc => scc.str3))
    .IgnoreAllNonExisting();
```

With simple words how to map an object to the first item of the array in destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.bstr1, exp => exp.MapFrom(src => src.str2))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.bstr2, exp => exp.MapFrom(src => src.str3));

Mapper.CreateMap<A, C>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.cstr1, exp => exp.MapFrom(scc => scc.str1))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.barr1, exp => exp.ResolveUsing<AToBCollectionResolver>());
```

Where `AToBCollectionResolver`:

```
class AToBCollectionResolver : ValueResolver<A, IEnumerable<B>>
{
    protected override IEnumerable<B> ResolveCore(A source)
    {
        return new[] { Mapper.Map<B>(source)};
    }
}
```